# Натуральные числа, в бинарной записи которых единицы идут парами

Tags: python, python-3.x, системы-счисления

Будем рассматривать натуральные числа, в двоичной записи которых единицы идут парами. То есть рядом с каждой единицей есть ещё одна единица, но никакие три единицы не идут подряд. Для удобства, дадим таким числам название. Скажем, **парноединичные**. Например, число 27 является парноединичным, так как его бинарная запись выглядит следующим образом: 11011. А число 47 не подходит, так как в двоичной системе у него найдутся три единицы, идущие подряд: 10**111**1. Вот первые несколько парноединичных чисел: 3, 6, 12, 24, 27, 48, 51, 54, 96, 99, 102, 108, 192, 195, 198, ...

Итак, нам нужно написать программу, выводящую все парноединичные числа в заданном пользователем диапазоне (проверкой на дуракоустойчивость можно пренебречь).

У меня получился вот такой швахкод (да и то после нескольких неудачных попыток):

```
k1=int(input())
k2=int(input())
for j in range (k1, k2+1):
    i=j
    flag=1
    while i!=0:
        if i%2==0:
            i=i//2
        else:
            i=i//2
            if i==0:
                flag=0
                break
            elif i!=0 and i%2==0:
                flag=0
                break 
            else:
                i=i//2
                if i%2==1:
                    flag=0
                    break
                elif i!=0:
                    i//=2
    if flag==1:
        print(j)
```

Мне кажется, что если бы я учился в школе, учительница информатики поставила бы мне за такие «художества» если не двойку, то тройку уж точно.
В связи с вышесказанным, я готов принять любые конструктивные замечания. Как по улучшению кода, так и по алгоритму.

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Крутота! В какой лес вы ходите по задачи? Там ещё много осталось? Как проголосовать за вопрос два раза? Как проголосовать за вопрос три раза?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, эту задачу придумала Катенька, а не я.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перебираем длины целых чисел в битах. Для каждой длины строим битовые представления парноединичных чисел. Начинаем со старших битов, двигаемcя к младшим. Числа генерируются в порядке возрастания. Отдельная проверка сделана чтобы исключить числа меньше стартовой величины.

```
def gen(start):

    def gen(bits, sum_, term, i):
        if sum_ + 2 * term < start:
            return

        if i < 0:
            if not(bits[1] == 0 and bits[0] == 1):
                yield sum_
            return

        if not(bits[i + 2] == 0 and bits[i + 1] == 1):
            yield from gen(bits, sum_, term // 2, i - 1)

        if not(bits[i + 2] == 1 and bits[i + 1] == 1):
            bits[i] = 1
            yield from gen(bits, sum_ + term, term // 2, i - 1)
            bits[i] = 0

    n = 0
    while True:
        bits = [0] * (n + 2)
        bits[n] = 1
        term = 2 ** n
        sum_ = term
        yield from gen(bits, sum_, term // 2, n - 1)
        n += 1


def main():
    n1, n2 = map(int, input().split())
    for i in gen(n1):
        if i > n2:
            break
        print(i, bin(i))


main()
```

Минимальный тест:

> ```
> $ echo 1 200 | python twin-bits.py
> 3 0b11
> 6 0b110
> 12 0b1100
> 24 0b11000
> 27 0b11011
> 48 0b110000
> 51 0b110011
> 54 0b110110
> 96 0b1100000
> 99 0b1100011
> 102 0b1100110
> 108 0b1101100
> 192 0b11000000
> 195 0b11000011
> 198 0b11000110
> ```

Исследование "дыры" в районе 3 * 2<sup>37</sup>:

> ```
> $ time echo 235_609_634_400 412_316_860_512 | python twin-bits.py
> 235609634400 0b11011011011011011011011011011001100000
> 235609634403 0b11011011011011011011011011011001100011
> 235609634406 0b11011011011011011011011011011001100110
> 235609634412 0b11011011011011011011011011011001101100
> 235609634496 0b11011011011011011011011011011011000000
> 235609634499 0b11011011011011011011011011011011000011
> 235609634502 0b11011011011011011011011011011011000110
> 235609634508 0b11011011011011011011011011011011001100
> 235609634520 0b11011011011011011011011011011011011000
> 235609634523 0b11011011011011011011011011011011011011
> 412316860416 0b110000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 412316860419 0b110000000000000000000000000000000000011
> 412316860422 0b110000000000000000000000000000000000110
> 412316860428 0b110000000000000000000000000000000001100
> 412316860440 0b110000000000000000000000000000000011000
> 412316860443 0b110000000000000000000000000000000011011
> 412316860464 0b110000000000000000000000000000000110000
> 412316860467 0b110000000000000000000000000000000110011
> 412316860470 0b110000000000000000000000000000000110110
> 412316860512 0b110000000000000000000000000000001100000
>
> real  0m0.025s
> user  0m0.024s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

> ```
> $ time echo 1 412_316_860_512 | python twin-bits.py | wc -l
> 1822482
>
> real  0m10.329s
> user  0m10.316s
> sys   0m0.160s
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Я бы особо не мудрил: https://ideone.com/tT7GT4

```
def check(x):
  while x:
    if (x&7) == 7: return False
    if (x&3) == 1: return False
    x >>= 1 + (x&1)
  return True

print([x for x in range(1, 200) if check(x)])
```

```
[3, 6, 12, 24, 27, 48, 51, 54, 96, 99, 102, 108, 192, 195, 198]
```

Допускаю, что можно сделать эффективнее, но может и так пойдёт?

Comment: Этому идельному (без сарказма) решению, недостаёт немного пояснений.

Comment: @Namerek, ваше решение проверяет одно число за время пропорциональное числу бит в нём. Решение Qwertiy требует квадратичного времени от числа бит. Оно опередит ваше на маленьких числах, но отстанет когда число бит станет расти.

Comment: С какого перепугу у меня квадратичное время? Битовый сдвиг это одна операция, а не цикл. Стоп, или ты про biginteger? Да, для него не лучший вариант.

Comment: Да, я про длинные целые. Полагаю что на десятках тысяч бит начнёт тормозить. Но это теоретическое рассуждение. На таком количестве бит мы просто не доберёмся до следующего числа. Чем больше бит, тем шире становятся дырки. Не все, но некоторые.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а преобразование в бинарную строку точно делается эффективно, а не тем же сдвигом? А то и вообще делением, которое медленнее сдвига в разы?

Comment: Числа хранятся в двоичном виде. Преобразование именно в бинарную строку делается за линейное время от числа бит (там "слова" по 30 бит, каждое слово отображается в строку из 30 символов). А вот в десятичную - за квадрат (есть такой недостаток в Питоне). Есть ситуации когда вычисляется значение быстро, а распечатать его в десятичном виде не получается. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, прикольно, запомню. А то понимать, что при желании так можно сделать и знать, что сделано именно так - это совершенно разные вещи)

Answer (score 4):

Если во всех "парноединичных" числах заменить `11` на `1`, то получится [данная](https://oeis.org/A003714) последовательность. Первая функция в коде создают эту последовательность. Далее я прохожу по всем значения последовательности и заменяют `1` на `11`

```
def fibbinary():
    x = 0
    while True:
        yield x
        y = ~(x >> 1)
        x = (x - y) & y

def f(n):
    result = []
    for el in fibbinary():
        if el.bit_length() > n.bit_length():
            break
        el = int(bin(el).replace("1", "11"), 2)
        if el > n:
            continue
        result.append(el)
    return sorted(result)
```

Comment: А в чём суть кода?

Comment: Красивая идея !

Answer (score 3):

Прям, не знаю, устроит ли такой костыльный вариант, но предложу:

```py
import re

for i in range(200):
    string_value = bin(i).removeprefix('0b')
    if not(
            set(
                filter(
                    bool, 
                    re.split(r'0+', string_value))
            ) ^ {'11'}
    ) and '11' in string_value:
        print(i, bin(i))
```

Вывод:

```latex
3 0b11
6 0b110
12 0b1100
24 0b11000
27 0b11011
48 0b110000
51 0b110011
54 0b110110
96 0b1100000
99 0b1100011
102 0b1100110
108 0b1101100
192 0b11000000
195 0b11000011
198 0b11000110
```

Можно сжать до однострочника

```py
import re

numbers = [
    i for i in range(200)
    if not (
            set(
                filter(
                    bool,
                    re.split(r'0+', bin(i).removeprefix('0b')))
            ) ^ {'11'}
    ) and '11' in bin(i).removeprefix('0b')
]

print(*numbers, sep='\n')
```

UPD: Тоже самое без регулярок

```py
for i in range(200):
    string_value = bin(i).removeprefix('0b')
    modified = set(filter(bool, string_value.split('0')))
    if not (modified ^ {'11'}) and modified:
        print(i, bin(i))
```

Answer (score 2):

доработал свой прямой как доска вариант, но на больших числах будет довольно медленно.

```
def check(number):
    b = bin(number)
        if "111" not in b and not "010" in b \
            and b.startswith("0b11") and not b.endswith("01"):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Одолжил идею обработки битовых строк.

Answer (score 1):

Число переведём в строку битов и поищем там комбинации `111` и `010`. Если комбинация найдена, нам такое число не годится и надо его поправить. Например:

> ```
>     плохая комбинация
>     ---
> 11001110011
>
>        1111 - маска которая начинается после плохой комбинации
> 11001111111 - накадываем маску (логическое ИЛИ)
> 11010000000 - добавляем единицу
> ```

Заметьте что между `11001110011` и `11001111111` хороших чисел быть не может. Мы их все разом пропускаем. После пропуска не обязательно получится парноединичное число, тогда нужно снова найти дефектное место и "пропустить" его.

Ещё пример для комбинации `010`:

> ```
>     плохая комбинация
>     ---
> 11000100011
>
>        1111 - маска которая начинается после плохой комбинации
> 11000101111 - накадываем маску (логическое ИЛИ)
> 11000110000 - добавляем единицу
> ```

И снова между `11000100011` и `11000101111` хороших чисел быть не может. И снова мы их пропускаем в одну операцию.

Отдельно надо обработать `10` в начале строки и `01` в конце. Последнее исключение - число `1`.

Этот вариант с точки зрения О-большого медленнее чем генератор, но на практике для небольших чисел он самый быстрый.

```
def defect(bits):
    if bits == '1':
        return 0
    if bits[:2] == '10':
        return 1
    i = bits.find('010')
    if i >= 0:
        return i + 2
    i = bits.find('111')
    if i >= 0:
        return i + 2
    if bits[-2:] == '01':
        return len(bits) - 1
    return -1


def next_twin_bit(n):
    while True:
        bits = bin(n)[2:]
        i = defect(bits)
        if i == -1:
            return n
        j = len(bits) - i - 1
        bit = 1 << j
        mask = bit - 1
        n = (n | mask) + 1


def twin_bits(n):
    while True:
        n = next_twin_bit(n)
        yield n
        n += 1


def main():
    n1, n2 = map(int, input().split())
    for i in twin_bits(n1):
        if i > n2:
            break
        print(i, bin(i))


main()
```

Минимальный тест:

> ```
> $ echo 1 200 | python twin-bits-2.py
> 3 0b11
> 6 0b110
> 12 0b1100
> 24 0b11000
> 27 0b11011
> 48 0b110000
> 51 0b110011
> 54 0b110110
> 96 0b1100000
> 99 0b1100011
> 102 0b1100110
> 108 0b1101100
> 192 0b11000000
> 195 0b11000011
> 198 0b11000110
> ```

"Дыра" вокруг 3 * 2<sup>37</sup>:

> ```
> $ time echo 235_609_634_400 412_316_860_512 | python twin-bits-2.py
> 235609634400 0b11011011011011011011011011011001100000
> 235609634403 0b11011011011011011011011011011001100011
> 235609634406 0b11011011011011011011011011011001100110
> 235609634412 0b11011011011011011011011011011001101100
> 235609634496 0b11011011011011011011011011011011000000
> 235609634499 0b11011011011011011011011011011011000011
> 235609634502 0b11011011011011011011011011011011000110
> 235609634508 0b11011011011011011011011011011011001100
> 235609634520 0b11011011011011011011011011011011011000
> 235609634523 0b11011011011011011011011011011011011011
> 412316860416 0b110000000000000000000000000000000000000
> 412316860419 0b110000000000000000000000000000000000011
> 412316860422 0b110000000000000000000000000000000000110
> 412316860428 0b110000000000000000000000000000000001100
> 412316860440 0b110000000000000000000000000000000011000
> 412316860443 0b110000000000000000000000000000000011011
> 412316860464 0b110000000000000000000000000000000110000
> 412316860467 0b110000000000000000000000000000000110011
> 412316860470 0b110000000000000000000000000000000110110
> 412316860512 0b110000000000000000000000000000001100000
>
> real  0m0.026s
> user  0m0.020s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

> ```
> $ time echo 1 412_316_860_512 | python twin-bits-2.py | wc -l
> 1822482
>
> real  0m7.228s
> user  0m7.208s
> sys   0m0.112s
> ```